# How to install/ where to find jboss/fuse apache camel tools stand alone

Tags: apache-camel, jboss-tools

i want to install the apache camel tools for eclipse: http://tools.jboss.org/features/apachecamel.html

But how to install/ where to find camel tools? I tried to install JBoss Tools from eclipse marketplace but didn't find camel on selection screen. (don't want all tools)

I also tried the update site mentioned here http://tools.jboss.org/blog/2014-04-14-JBTIS-4.html but the only "camel" thing is "JBoss Fuse Camel Editor Feature" is this it?

Besides the visualizing of routes i want to see jmx stuff that is exposed by my camel app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [blog entry from Paul Leacu](http://tools.jboss.org/blog/2014-04-14-JBTIS-4.html) provides the correct information. There are currently 3 features which are named like "JBoss Fuse ...".

The Camel Editor feature provides the editor for designing your Camel Routes and to launch them on your local machine.

Then there is the Fuse Server Adapter feature which provides some server adapters for starting / stopping / installing Apache ServiceMix, Apache Karaf and JBoss Fuse servers.

Finally there is the Fuse Runtime feature which provides the JMX stuff you are looking for and the Fabric related functionality.

I made a short install guide on how to install JBoss Fuse Tooling without JBDS and/or the integration stack. You can find the guide [here](http://lhein.blogspot.com/2014/07/where-can-i-get-jboss-fuse-tooling-and.html).

Comment: Links are broken, due to old.